# Refreshing fragment UI within fragmentclass

Tags: java, android

I have a fragment which is wired up to a class. I have a background thread which does work in the background every 1 minute, and I need the UI to refresh specifically if the user is "watching" the screen.

The UI has some TextViews and such.
I update the UI via a Handler like this:

```
                    // Updating TextViews and such with textView.SetText(); ....
                    
                    if (isResumed()) {
                        try {
                            // This throws an error sometimes saying: getFragmentManager() can't be called on null instance
                            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new LiveViewFragment()).commitNow();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
```

**My question is:**
How can I **force** refresh the fragment?

Other code I've been trying is this:

```
 LiveViewFragment fragment = (LiveViewFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(fragment).attach(fragment).commit();
```

But this also fail sometimes.

Comment: Hey, it's not a good practice to "force refresh the fragment". Instead why don't you use live data or anything else to update your views inside the fragment ? It would be great if you can elaborate what you wanna update in the fragment

Comment: What do you mean by "live data"? Some TextViews gets updated in the background thread, but it doesn't show. I need to go out of the fragment, then into it again to see the changes.

Comment: Please share some code where you are performing updates

Comment: Use LiveData: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata

Answer (score 0):

it is not good practice to refresh a fragment . Instead why don't you use live data or anything else to update your views inside the fragment ?

whatever. you can try this simple function

```
  fun recreateFragment(fragment : Fragment) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().detach(fragment).commit()
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().attach(fragment).commit()
    } else {
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().detach(fragment).attach(fragment).commit()
    }
}
```